# Stepwise AIC - on which model is the forward- and backward step performed

Tags: regression, model-selection, aic, stepwise-regression

After I have read on different websites different claims, I hope that someone could may help me with the following question. :)

I refere to stepwise AIC w.r.t regression models. In fact, I wonder on which model the "Step 2" is performed. Is it really performed on the model  $M_{current}$ or is the backward step performed on the model one obtains **after** performing the forward step on the model $M_{current}$.
If the latter would hold, then it could happen that we may remove in the third step the covariate added in the second?

- Initialize: Full or empty model $M_{current}$
- Step 1: Perform a forward selection on $M_{current}$
- Step 2: Perform a backward selection on $M_{current}$
- Decision: For the updated $M_{current}$ model, choose the model of Step1 OR step2 which has the  lowest AIC

Thank you in advance for your help and clarification! :-)

Comment: Under the first of your scenarios, Step 1 would be useless.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @whuber ! Why would under my first assumption the first step be useless? In the final decision, I would choose the model of step 1 **or** step 2 which yields the lowest AIC. Or do I miss something?